# Html selects last variable option

Tags: html

im very new to html and am making a basic rock paper scissor page where you can select the image to choose your action. My issue is that it always selects the last option in the html.

```
  <form action="/result <%@choice = "rock"%>">
    <div id="rock_button" class="slideRight">
      <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/XT41ZXk.jpg" alt="Rock";>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form action="/result <%@choice = "paper"%>">
    <div id="paper_button" class="slideUp">
      <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/r1GckhD.jpg" alt="Paper";>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form action="/result <%@choice = "scissors"%>">
    <div id="scissors_button" class="slideLeft">
      <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ttUlD5y.jpg" alt="Scissors";>
    </div>
  </form>
```

So from the above code, @choice is always set to "scissors". regardless of which picture is clicked on. ive tried putting  onclick="<%@choice = "paper"%>" within th input, without any luck and creating one large form for all three picures but nothing has worked. Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

The choice variable is only used within the current page: Before any of the images is even clicked.

Use one form. Use buttons. Give them a name and a value. Read the form data in the server side program that acts as your form handler.

```
  <form action="/result">
    <button id="rock_button" class="slideRight" name="choice" value="rock">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XT41ZXk.jpg" alt="Rock">
    </button>

    <button id="paper_button" class="slideUp" name="choice" value="paper">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/r1GckhD.jpg" alt="Paper">
    </button>

    <button id="scissors_button" class="slideLeft" name="choice" value="scissors">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ttUlD5y.jpg" alt="Scissors">
    </button>
  </form>
```

Then, in the program that handles the /result URL, you would do something along the lines of:

```
my $choice = $c->request->params->{choice};
```

The specifics depending on your choice of server side language.

Comment: amazing, thankyou. if im using sinatra and ruby how would  things look on the server side?

Comment: I don't use those tools, but reading form data from a query string is trivial in any server side environment. It's so fundamental to working on the WWW that any basic introductory tutorial should cover it.